# Blender - animating simple mesh hierarchy

Tags: animation, blender

honestly, browsed everywhere I could, but as you might have guessed, failed to find solution to my issue.
So I need very simple shape to show moving object. By design, it is just moving arrow. Simple, right?
The catch is that I also need to indicate it's movement speed. By design, it has to be trailing arrows. So something like ">" - standing, ">>" - slowly moving, ">>>" - moving at normal speed, ">>>>" - moving fast.
Here's my current sketch (it should have 3 sub arrow's in the end).

[image: arrow]
So the issue is that i want to make all this states as separate animations, so i can export it as single model and just switch animations as state changes.
But i can't figure out how to toggle their visibility.
It seems like there is no way to change state of the child if it is not an armature. I found one trick with vertex groups and masks, but it doesn't work(or maybe i can't figure it out) for miltiple levels, like in my case, when I need each animation to show different sets of subarrows.
So that's basically the question - how can I : a) animate structure like:
arrow
 |- speed1
 |- speed2
 |- speed3
(they all planes);
b) control visibility of more than 2 vertex groups;
c) maybe this is just wrong approach and there is proper way to do this.

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s not really a good way to change the topology of a single mesh in an animation; the usual way this is done is by taking the intended-to-be-hidden parts and scaling them down and/or moving them inside other parts of the mesh. If you can specify keyframes in at least as high a frame rate as your animations will be played back, you can make the appearance/disappearance of the pieces of the mesh “instantaneous” by making the keyframes adjacent.

Comment: Thanks for response, but this way there is no way to export it as single mesh with animations embedded(or at least i don't know how). I ended up using armature, assigning bone to each "fin" and keying scaling.